# Swift optionals and equality operator

Tags: swift, operators, option-type

Looking for a doc reference or a name or link on this particular behavior, which is similar to optional binding but isn't talked about in that part of the docs.

I can test an optional with the `==` operator, and test against both `nil` and its actual value, without doing any explicit unwrapping:

```
var toggle: Bool? = nil
if (toggle == true || toggle == nil) {
    // do something
}
```

This compiles and works as you'd want it to, but what's happened here is that I haven't had to unwrap `toggle!` explicitly; the `==` has safely done it for me.

It's convenient but I confess to being a little surprised when I noticed it. Is this just a behavior of the default `==` implementation? Or is something else in the language happening here? Thanks for insight.

Comment: If you command-click on the `==` then you'll see that there is a `public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool` which takes two optionals as operands.

Comment: Indeed, but why should it? Is this philosophical in the language design? Or just a convenience? Or am I thinking too hard about it?

Comment: It is convenience, I think. The comparison operators taking optionals where removed in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md. But the equality operators remained: *"Variants of == and != which accept optional operands are still useful, and their results unsurprising, so they will remain."*

Comment: @MartinR. Thanks. That link is super helpful & interesting

Comment: @MartinR command click no longer works in Xcode? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BradThomas: Which Xcode version are you using? Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870050/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR 10.3 OK thanks, I'll check that out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Swift has an equality operator taking two optionals values
(of an Equatable base type):

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

The implementation can be found at [Optional.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift):

```
public func == <T: Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l == r
  case (nil, nil):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

and it does what one would expect: The operands are equal if they
are both `nil`, or if they are both not `nil` and the unwrapped
values are equal.

Similar comparison operators `<`  etc taking optionals have been
removed in Swift 3, compare
[SE-0121 Remove Optional Comparison Operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md):

> Remove the versions of <, <=, >, and >= which accept optional operands.
>
> Variants of == and != which accept optional operands are still useful, and their results unsurprising, so they will remain.

So this works as expected:

```
let b: Bool? = nil
print(b == true) // prints "false"
```

But as matt pointed out, this can not be done with implicitly unwrapped
optionals, here the left operand will be unwrapped:

```
let b: Bool! = nil
print(b == true) // crashes
```

Comment: Warning: Don't try this with an implicitly unwrapped Optional. Horrible Things (tm) can happen.

Comment: @matt Nothing happened in swift 5.6 . App does not crash .