# How can I find the operator definition in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, operator-keyword, definition

I write code below:

```
let array1: [Int] = [0,1]
let array2 = array1 + [2]
```

It just works.I want to find where `+` operator define. I search ArrayExtension in my workspace without result.I search Apple doc `Collection` `Sequence` `Array` , there is no result.

Is there a way to navigate to `operator definition`  ,like `CMD + CTRL + J` for `func`

Comment: CMD + CTRL + J should work if you select the `+` in the Xcode source editor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I always  use `Mouse + CMD + CTRL`, unexpected `Hot Key `works for `Operator`.  `Mouse + CMD + CTRL` does not work for `Operator`.

Comment: When update to `Xcode 10.2.1`, `CMD + CTRL + J` cannot jump to `operator definition`.Anyother way?

Comment: `Xcode 11 ` works. CMD + CTRL + J comes back  .

Comment: **Update for Xcode 14:** Unfortunately, this does not work in Xcode 14.1 anymore. There is currently no way to “jump” to the definition of an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for Xcode 13:** Unfortunately, this does not work in Xcode 13 anymore. There is currently no way to “jump” to the definition of an operator.

**Previous answer for Xcode 11:** You can select the operator in the Xcode source editor, and choose "Navigate -> Jump to definition" from the menu, or press CMD+CTRL+J.

(This was broken in Xcode 10, but works again in Xcode 11, which is currently in beta.)

Comment: CMD-CTRL-Click works as well in Xcode 11, or Option-Click.

Comment: Does this still work in Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100)? Neither Option-click nor selecting the operator and choosing _Navigate_ > _Jump to definition_ nor ⌘⌃-click do anything.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: You are right, it seems that it does not work anymore in Xcode 13. That is a pity.