# Xcode 10.2.1: Jump to Operator Definition?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10.2

I'm working on a Swift codebase in Xcode, and there are a bunch of custom operators. Usually, for regular symbols/functions/variables, I can just press ctrl + cmd + click on it and the editor will jump to the definition. In other versions of Xcode, I can use ctrl + cmd + j to jump to the operator def. Is there a way to do this in Xcode 10.2.1? Or is there a bug in that version?

Comment: See the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53651936/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thank you! I'm currently on 10.2.1, and CTRL + CMD + J doesn't seem to work. That user indicated that it would work for Xcode 11 – do you know of anything that will work for 10.2.1? Also, if you post it as an answer I'd love to give you credit!

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a workaround for Xcode 10. – I have added an answer to the original question.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 10.2.1. If by "custom operators" you mean methods you've implemented in your project, this works fine for me: **CMD+CTRL+click** will jump from a call to the declaration(or definition)., **CMD+click** will give you a menu.